# Mapping string array with if-statement

Tags: arrays, swift, string, if-statement, mapping

I want to map from string to string but I get this error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'String'

My Code:

```
var months: [String] = ["sonbahar", "kis", "ilkbahar", "yaz"]
var aylar: [String]

aylar = months.map { _ in return

if months == "sonbahar" {
    print("eylul ekim kasim")
}
if months == "kis" {
    print("aralik ocak subat")
}
if months == "ilkbahar" {
    print("mart nisan mayis")
}
if months == "yaz" {
    print("haziran temmuz agustos")
}
}
```

I tried mapping from string array to string array. I want to see as I showed but taking error.

Comment: replace `print(...)` with `return ...` everywhere and the code `_ in return` is just wrong, replace it with `month in` and then replace `months` with `month` to use the input variable

Comment: is there a way to make them directly dictionary by mapping? like ["winter" : "December January February", "autumn" : "September.....]

Comment: If the mapping isn't dynamic you might as well create a hard coded dictionary directly. And you might also want to consider using an array of strings (months) as the value in the dictionary instead of a string containing the months.